# How to add border-bottom with a triangle on a div which is inside a row

Tags: html, angular, css, typescript, flexbox

Ok. I have an Angular2 application. Im using an angular component called flex-layout (that let me work with flexbox through directives, thats all). Then, i have a div with class="row" and a dynamic amount of divs inside it. Each dynamic div have an image inside of it.

I need to mark one of those divs as selected, and then add an specific class to it. That class has to put a border-bottom and a background color (already do that), but i need to add a little triangle at the middle of the border-botom on selected div.

[Work already done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0v6a.png)

---

[Fail when selecting another div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylIy7.png)

---

As you see on the above images, i managed to put that triangle on the middle of all row (no matter what div i selected)

But, when i change the selected div, triangle doesnt move at all. It always stays at center of the row, and i need the triangle be at the center of selected div instead.

```js
changeSelectedBrand(brandId: number) {
    this.selectedBrand = brandId;
  }
```

```css
div.image-row {
    height: 90px;
    max-height: 90px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
  }

  .div-image-row-selected {
    background-color: #DDDDDD !important;
    border-bottom: 3px solid mat-color($primary,400);
  }

  .div-image-row-selected:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: solid 10px mat-color($primary,400);
    border-left: solid 10px transparent;
    border-right: solid 10px transparent;
  }
  
  div.image-row > img {
    height: 65px;
  }
```

```html
<div fxLayout="row">
                      <div fxFlex="100%" fxLayoutAlign="center center" class="image-row" *ngFor="let brand of brands" [ngClass]="{'div-image-row-selected': brand.id === selectedBrand}" (click)="changeSelectedBrand(brand.id)">
                        <img src="{{brand.url}}" />
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

The snippet is not functional, i know... is just to show you how things are done right now.

So, repeat the question: How can i make that triangle to move to the center of the bottom border of a selected div?

Thank you

Comment: Please provide a working example. No way to debug your code like this.

Answer (score 0):

put a position relative wrapper for `div.image-row` and then update the triangle style(`.div-image-row-selected:after`) with required left.

```
div.image-row {
    height: 90px;
    max-height: 90px;
    width: 100px;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;

    position: relative;
  }

.div-image-row-selected:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: calc(50% - 10px);
    right: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: solid 10px #ff0000;
    border-left: solid 10px transparent;
    border-right: solid 10px transparent;
  }
```